# How can I let the image of a button change by clicking it?

Tags: html, css, image, button, onclick

I'd like to have the image of a button changing to another picture of the same size, and after a certain amount of time changed back. For example, you click on a picture of a house, it will change to the sky, then without any action back to the house. The time between the 2nd picture changing back to the 1st should not prohibit the button being clicked again.

So, since I'm fairly new, I searched a lot but couldn't find something regarding my problem, or something I understood. I made a button in HTML, linked a class in CSS which has the URL of the image that's supposed to act as the button. So far, it works. 
How do I continue?

```
 -> HTML
<button class="buttonn" > 
-> CSS
.buttonn {
 background-image:url([Link to the image]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider transition and delay on active state:

```css
button {
  padding:20px;
  border:none;
  background-image:
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200),
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/200/200);
  background-size:0 0,cover; /* The top one invisible*/
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition: 0s 1s;
}
button:active {
  background-size:100% 100%,cover;
  transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```

Like this too:

```css
button {
  padding:20px;
  border:none;
  background-image:
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/200/200);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition: 0s 1s;
}
button:active {
  background-image:
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200);
  transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: @DumbQuestionButAnswerAnywayPle you have for sure more CSS involved, if you can show me your full code I can help, without it's difficult

Comment: @DumbQuestionButAnswerAnywayPle there is nothing complex in the code so I don't think it's a lack of support or something. can you at least show me a screenshot of the whole code? even the HTML standard sutff like body can create issue

Comment: @DumbQuestionButAnswerAnywayPle and the CSS?

Comment: @DumbQuestionButAnswerAnywayPle try to add quotes `url("https://picsum.photos/id/10/200/200")` also check the dev tab to see if the CSS is loading or not, probably the path is not ok.